# Speed issues with ReaderWriterLockSlim and Garbage Collection

Tags: garbage-collection, readerwriterlockslim

I have an example piece of code the illustrates issues in my code when GC.Collect is carried out on a class having a ReaderWriterLockSlim member variable. The GC.Collect takes between 2 and 3 seconds to run. I need to carry out GC at regular intervals because my applicaton is extremely memory intensive.

```
namespace WpfApplication12
{
    public class DataItem
    {
        private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim m_propertyLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

        public DataItem()
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<DataItem> dataItemList = new List<DataItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                dataItemList.Add(new DataItem());
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            GC.Collect();
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone had similar problems?

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask if you really need a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for each of your `DataItem` classes?

Seems like bad design to me to have that many handles floating about. After-all, that's what will be causing the delay...

Answer (score 0):

The memory issue may be caused if the readerwriterlockslim is called from multiple threads. I believe it will store some information of the threads which can cause the memory consumption to bloat. I would recommend trying to figure out a solution where you can bring down the number of thread that are calling the readerwriterlockslim.